# Program works fine in JSFiddle, but goes pear shaped when outputted on Opera browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, opera

I have asked this question before, and was provided with a perfect answer by the user "Cristian Olaru" -- I say perfect because when I ran it in JSFiddle that he provided, I got exactly the result that I was looking for.

But when I ran it on my browser, the image icons of three cars appeared, but there were no text boxes and no submit button when I placed my mouse pointer on the image.

I am showing you EXACTLY the code that Cristian provided me, with the exception that I have added a background colour and have added some HTML tags like `DOCTYPE HTML` and `HEAD` which JSFiddle does not come equipped with.

I have changed nothing else. What you see is identical to Cristian's code. Is there a reason why a code executes perfectly in JSFiddle but not in a browser?

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <head>
       <style>

       body {
       background-color: #ADD8E6;
      }

      #form {
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-right: -50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
      }

     .car {
     float: left;
     margin: 2% 2% 5% 2%;
     }

     .car label img {
     transform: scale(0.8);
     transition-duration: 0.2s;
     }

     .car label img:hover {
     cursor: pointer;
     transform: scale(1);
     }

     .comment {
     position: absolute;
     visibility: hidden;
     }

    .comment input {
    width: 128px;
    font-size: 1em;
    }

   .car label img {
   width: 128px;
   display: block;
   }

   #button {
   position: relative;
   left: 66%;
   margin: 2%;
   visibility: hidden;
   }

   </style>
   </head>
   <body>

   <div id="form">
   <form method="post" action="#">

   <div class="car">
   <label for="mercedesbenz">
   <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
   </label>

   <div class="comment">
   <input type="text" id="mercedesbenz" placeholder="Merc" />
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="car">
   <label for="porche">
   <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
   </label>
   <div class="comment">
   <input type="text" id="Porche" placeholder="Porc" />
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="car">
   <label for="bmw">
   <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
   </label>
   <div class="comment">
   <input type="text" id="bmw" placeholder="Beemer" />
   </div>
   </div>
   <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
   </div>


   <script>
   $('.car').click(function() {
   $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
   $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");

   var id = $(this).children('label').attr('for');
   var buttonOffset;
   switch(id) {
   case 'mercedesbenz':
   buttonOffset = '0';
   break;
   case 'porche':
   buttonOffset = '33%';
   break;
   case 'bmw':
   buttonOffset = '66%';
   break;
   }

   $(this).children('.comment').css("visibility", "visible");
   $('#button').css("left", buttonOffset);
   $('#button').css("visibility", "visible");
   });

   $('.comment').mouseleave(function() {
   setTimeout(function () {
   $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
   $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");
   }, 500);
   });

   </script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Because you aren't including jQuery?

Comment: There were no jQueries in Cristian's code.

Comment: `$('#button').css("left", buttonOffset);` looks like jQuery to me.

Comment: `$` is the jQuery object alias, so there is jQuery present here. Make sure you have it included in the `<head>` element (and is the first thing you import if jQuery libraries are also being used).

Comment: Drew, I appreciate that input, thanks.

Comment: @Jason12 if the answer helps you, please select it as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the screenshot of that JSFiddle.

[image: jQuery 2.1.0 is included]

This is the reason why your code did not run when you tried to implement it without including the jQuery library.

To fix the issue, add this in the header

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js'></script>
```

Comment: Isabel, I am so grateful to you for giving me (someone who is fairly good in PHP but hopeless in JavaScript/JQuery) a straight answer!

Comment: Cheer up. This is a good question for people who may not be familiar with JSFiddle. I am sorry that you got down voted. I'm not good at php at all so who knows? One day you may help me on that. Best wishes. :)